# Creating Unique Access Codes Per Email Address in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to create a system for a classified ads-type site that allows users to create ad postings without going through any kind of account registration process. I want to have a unique access code associated with each email address that users use to make posts. This access code will later be used by users to gain access to the set of posts that they've made in the past.

So these access codes should be not only unique but also secure / unguessable. Any suggestions for what I can look into for implementing this with Ruby on Rails? I haven't been able to find much in researching the topic - most related discussion seems to be around encrypting passwords, hashing, etc, so any general direction is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the user's id, add a strong salt to it and create a SHA1 with the result. For example `string = user.id.to_s + 'h2Das!di$' ; encrypted_access_code = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(string)`

Comment: `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 #=> "b4GOKm4pOYU_-BOXcrUGDg"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [generate a hash with a salt](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) to create an identifier for each email address.  You should make sure two people cannot get the same hash.

It's worth mentioning that the length of this random and unique acces code will be much longer and harder to remember than a username and password.

Answer (score 1):

> **SecureRandom.hex**(n=nil) click to toggle source ::hex generates a random hex string.
>
> The argument n specifies the length of the random length. The length
>   of the result string is twice of n.
>
> If n is not specified, 16 is assumed. It may be larger in future.
>
> The result may contain 0-9 and a-f.

```
p SecureRandom.hex #=> "eb693ec8252cd630102fd0d0fb7c3485"
p SecureRandom.hex #=> "91dc3bfb4de5b11d029d376634589b61"
```